# AddAfterSelf and line return with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

i have this code for to dupplicate a xml element in a XDocument object.

```
//get a copy of element
XElement element = new XElement(this._xmldoc.Descendants(name).LastOrDefault());
//add element
this._xmldoc.Descendants(name).LastOrDefault().AddAfterSelf(element);
```

[EDIT]

This is my "save" method

```
/// <summary>
/// Method used to save document
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filePath">file path</param>
public bool Save(string filePath)
{
    //value to return
    bool returnValue = true;
    //clean empty elements
    returnValue &= this.CleanEmptyElements();
    //normalize xml text
    returnValue &= this.NormalizeDocument();
    try
    {
        //save document
        this._xmldoc.Save(filePath);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        returnValue = false;
    }
    //if save operation has failed
    if (!returnValue)
        //delete file
        File.Delete(filePath);
    //end of method
    return returnValue;
}
```

[/EDIT]

My code works good, but after dupplication, i have a little issue and i have this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Invoice>
    <Party>
        <Country>FRANCE</Country>
    </Party><Party>
        <Country>SPAIN</Country>
    </Party>
</Invoice>
```

And i want to have this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Invoice>
    <Party>
        <Country>FRANCE</Country>
    </Party>
    <Party>
        <Country>SPAIN</Country>
    </Party>
</Invoice>
```

So my question is, how to have a line return after my original element and before my copy?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason you can't just reformat on save? (I'd expect `XDocument.Save` to do this automatically unless you specify `SaveSettings.DisableFormatting`.)

Comment: How are you saving yours _xmldoc can you post this code as well ?

Comment: I use the save method, but my xml is not 'well' formated...

Comment: You need one root element, Parties for example that has your Party elements underneath

Comment: Whitespace (newlines) is not relevant in XML...  And indeed a well-formed XML doc can have only 1 root element.

Comment: I have already a root name, i'll edit my question for to show this

Comment: The default behaviour for xLinq is to add the newline. So take a critical look at CleanEmptyElements() and NormalizeDocument().

Answer (score 1):

When you parse the document, use:

```
this._xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(yourXmlString);
```

instead of:

```
this._xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(yourXmlString, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

Comment: I never parse my document, i only create a XDocument and save it into a file